# Silverlight 4 Button MouseOver when Button moves, not Mouse

Tags: silverlight, animation

I have a situation where I have a series of buttons scrolling by in a Grid inside a Canvas animated with a Storyboard and DoubleAnimation (on the Canvas.LeftProperty).

When I move the mouse over the buttons I get the expected MouseOver transition to the MouseOver VisualState.  But when the button moves under the mouse (that isn't moving) the MouseOver transition doesn't trigger.

I know MouseMove isn't triggered without moving the mouse, but is there anyway to get the Button to check for MouseOver when an animation is moving the buttons under the mouse cursor?